# iOS Prevent universal links across subdomains

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

1. The user is on www.example.com
2. Clicking links on the website keeps them in Safari
3. They click sign in which takes them to login.example.com in Safari
4. They click the sign in button which takes them back to www.example.com
5. Safari thinks the user has opened the website from a different domain and so opens the App using Universal Links.

How can I make it so that the subdomains are treated as one. The user shouldn't be switched to the app after login as they were browsing the website before. In the app entitlements only applinks:www.example.com has been added. If I add applinks:login.example.com then when they click sign in on the website I assume they will be taken to the app instead.

Comment: So when do you want universal links to work?

Comment: you can try

https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/

Comment: The universal links should work when they open a link from an external site like Google, or app like Notes or Messages. They just shouldn't work when the user is already on the same domain (as the intent of the user to be on the website should be respected)

Comment: We need to use universal links not URL schemes, as this is the modern way of doing it and it means the app will open automatically from 3rd party website/apps.

Comment: @Jonathan you could workaround this with specific prefix in URL path for Universal Links (ex: `www.example.com/iosapp/...`) and place this prefix where you definetely want to redirect users into the app.

Comment: @brigadir We don't want to do anything that is specific to the app, as that is the whole point of Universal links. Also the website is already heavily used so we can't change URLs even if we wanted to.

Comment: @Jonathan. did you ever figure out a solution?